# scalikejdbc, return generated ids for batch insert

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

I want to get all generated ids when batch insert gets executed.
I use scalikejdbc 2.3.5. Is that possible at all? Couldn't find anything in docs

Answer (score 1):

The operation is not supported yet in 2.3.x series. Since 2.4.0, it will be possible. 2.4.0 will be out this month. https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/pull/492

Comment: Will the generated ids be returned in correct order according to the inserts (input)?